# Trace back - find if a string value occurs before another specific string value - dplyr/R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a general problem in R. I wonder if there's a way to identify if a specific string value occurs after another specific string value within a group. The dataset is a time series. Each Group consist of 10 years.

I want something like the below, but instead of lag I wish to look at every year before " stringvalue1" within the group.

```
mutate(new_var = if_else(stringvar = "stringvalue1" & lag(stringvar) %in% c("stringvalue2", "stringvalue3"), "Match", "Not match"))
```

Help would be much appreciated!

```
library(dplyr)

match_if_precedes <- function(column, this_string, preceded_by)
{
  matches    <- which(column == this_string)
  if (length(matches) == 0) return(rep("No Match", length(column)))
  last_match = matches[length(matches) - 1]
  if (last_match == 0) return(rep("No Match", length(column)))
  any_matches <- !is.na(preceded_by %in% column[1:last_match])
  if(length(any_matches) == 0) return(rep("No Match", length(column)))
  any_matches <- any(any_matches)
  if(any_matches) return(rep("Match", length(column)))
  return(rep("No Match", length(column)))
}

df1 <- structure(list(group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A",  
                               "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                               "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
                     stringvar = c("stringvalue4", "stringvalue2", "stringvalue1", "stringvalue1", "stringvalue1", 
                                   "stringvalue1", "stringvalue1", "stringvalue1", "stringvalue1","stringvalue4", 
                                   "stringvalue4", "stringvalue2", "stringvalue3", "stringvalue3", "stringvalue4")),
                                   row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
df1 %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(newvar = match_if_precedes(stringvar, "stringvalue1", 
                                    c("stringvalue2", "stringvalue3"))) 

   group stringvar    newvar  
   <chr> <chr>        <chr>   
 1 A     stringvalue4 Match   
 2 A     stringvalue2 Match   
 3 A     stringvalue1 Match   
 4 A     stringvalue1 Match   
 5 A     stringvalue1 Match   
 6 B     stringvalue1 Match   
 7 B     stringvalue1 Match   
 8 B     stringvalue1 Match   
 9 B     stringvalue1 Match   
10 B     stringvalue4 Match   
11 C     stringvalue4 No Match
12 C     stringvalue2 No Match
13 C     stringvalue3 No Match
14 C     stringvalue3 No Match
15 C     stringvalue4 No Match
```

Comment: Usually, it is easier to help if you could include a reproducible example of your data and provide expected output. [Read here on how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function that will return a vector of "Match" if the criteria are met, and a vector of "No Match" if the criteria are not met. These will be the same length as the input column.

I have added extensive comments to show how the function works:

```r
# This function takes a vector of strings called `column`. It looks for any instances of the
# single string `this_string` and any of the vector of strings `preceded_by` within 
# `column`. If it finds any member of `preceded_by` in the vector before the last instance
# of `this_string` it returns a vector of the string "Match" with the same length as 
# the original `column` vector. In all other cases it returns a vector of "No Match"

match_if_precedes <- function(column, this_string, preceded_by)
{
  # Find instances of this_string. If there are no instances of this_string then
  # we want to return a vector of "No Match"
  matches    <- which(column == this_string)
  if (length(matches) == 0) return(rep("No Match", length(column)))

  # If there is more than one instance of this_string, we want to choose the last one
  last_match = matches[length(matches)] - 1

  # If the only instance of this_string is at position 1, there can't be any
  # instances of preceded_by before it, so return a vector of NA
  if (last_match == 0) return(rep("No Match", length(column)))

  # Now find the instances of preceded_by in the part of the column before the
  # last instance of this_string and remove any NA values
  any_matches <- preceded_by %in% column[1:last_match]
  any_matches <- any_matches[!is.na(any_matches)]

  # If no matches are valid, we return all NAs
  if(length(any_matches) == 0) return(rep("No Match", length(column)))

  # If any of our matches are TRUE, we return a vector of "Match"
  if(any(any_matches)) return(rep("Match", length(column)))

  # The only remaining possibility is that we had no matches, so return "No Match"
  return(rep("No Match", length(column)))
}
```

We can test this using the data from your question as modified by your comments:

```
df <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    stringvar = c("stringvalue4", "stringvalue2", "stringvalue1", 
    "stringvalue1", "stringvalue1", "stringvalue1", "stringvalue1", 
    "stringvalue1", "stringvalue1", "stringvalue4", "stringvalue4", 
    "stringvalue2", "stringvalue3", "stringvalue3", "stringvalue1"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

find_these  <- c("stringvalue2", "stringvalue3")
before_this <- "stringvalue1"
```

Now I can use `group_by` and `mutate` to apply this function to each of the groups in the data frame:

```r
library(dplyr)

df                                                                     %>%
group_by(group)                                                        %>% 
mutate(newvar = match_if_precedes(stringvar, before_this, find_these)) %>% 
as.data.frame()
```

Result:

```
#>    group    stringvar   newvar
#> 1      A stringvalue4    Match
#> 2      A stringvalue2    Match
#> 3      A stringvalue1    Match
#> 4      A stringvalue1    Match
#> 5      A stringvalue1    Match
#> 6      B stringvalue1 No Match
#> 7      B stringvalue1 No Match
#> 8      B stringvalue1 No Match
#> 9      B stringvalue1 No Match
#> 10     B stringvalue4 No Match
#> 11     C stringvalue4    Match
#> 12     C stringvalue2    Match
#> 13     C stringvalue3    Match
#> 14     C stringvalue3    Match
#> 15     C stringvalue1    Match
```

Comment: Thanks Allan. I'm not follow completly. :) Still quite new to R. What I look for is a match when stringvalue2 or stringvalue3 occurs before stringvalue1 in the time series.

Comment: Ah, sorry Henrik - I thought it was the other way around. I'll update in a minute.

Comment: My question has been criticised for being unclear, Thanks for making an effort!

Comment: @Henrik Does the updated version do what you were looking for?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. Hmm... Lets say we have group A. I want that group to be a "Match" (all rowns within the group) if a stringvalue1 occur in the group and that stringvalue2 or stringvalue3 has occured before the stringvalue1. Your function seems to only look for the lag value? And not find a match if stringvalue 2 are thrre years before the first stringvalue1. Hmm...

Comment: @ Allan Cameron I guess what I look for is to replace the lag function with a general before function.

Comment: @Henrik Yes, you're using mutate, so I presume you have dplyr loaded. Just group_by the group variable and make match_if_precedes return true if the group contains any true values. See my update.

Comment: @Hendrik  Sorry I misuderstood you. You want all of the group to be a match if Stringvalue2 or Stringvalue3 appear at any index in the group before Stringvalue1. I have updated the function to do this.

Comment: I added some example data above and your function. Group B shouldn't be a match since stringvalue2 or 3 does not precedes stringvalue1.

Comment: @Henrik Group B says "No Match"

Comment: @Henrik sorry - I thought you meant with my example

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. :) Yes I meant with my example.

Comment: Yes, thanks! :) But.. it's still isen't generic. I changed the last value in group c to Stringvalue1 and it returned: Error in if (last_match == 0) return(rep("No Match", length(column))) : 
  argument is of length zero

Comment: @Henrik another little bug fix - sorry! Should be working now

Comment: Tried it this morning on my large dataset. Pretty amazing :)  Next step is to understand how the functions works. I don't follow what happends inside completly. But it works very nice.

Comment: @Henrik I have added comments to the function to make it easier to follow what is happening inside.

Comment: Once again, thanks. I use this in a study of labor market integration in Sweden actually. :)  If I may ask one more thing... if I would like to change "# If there is more than one instance of this_string, we want to choose the last one" - to "# If there is more than one instance of this_string, we want to choose the first one". How could that be achived?

Comment: @Henrik change the line `last_match = matches[length(matches)] - 1` to `last_match = matches[1] - 1`

Comment: Got it! Thanks! :)